# How do I fix the error in loading handler to aws lamda function?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, aws-lambda, pulumi

I want to use spring boot in a aws lamda function. I have created the main class:

```
package com.baeldung.aws;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The controller class:

```
package com.baeldung.aws.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.baeldung.aws.data.User;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ProfileController {

    @GetMapping(value = "users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<User> getUser() {
        return List.of(new User("John", "Doe", "john.doe@baeldung.com"), new User("John", "Doe", "john.doe-2@baeldung.com"));
    }

}
```

And the handler class:

```
package com.baeldung.aws.handler;

import com.amazonaws.serverless.exceptions.ContainerInitializationException;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyResponse;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.HttpApiV2ProxyRequest;
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.baeldung.aws.Application;

public class HttpV2LambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<HttpApiV2ProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> {
    private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<HttpApiV2ProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

    static {
        try {
            handler = SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getHttpApiV2ProxyHandler(Application.class);
        } catch (ContainerInitializationException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load spring boot application", ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AwsProxyResponse handleRequest(HttpApiV2ProxyRequest input, Context context) {
        return handler.proxy(input, context);
    }
}
```

To build the following Gradle script is used.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.2'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

dependencies {
         implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.7.13'
         implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.7.13'
         implementation 'com.amazonaws.serverless:aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2:1.9.3'
         testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.7.13'
}

jar {
        manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart',
                   'Implementation-Version': version,
                   'Main-Class': 'com.baeldung.aws.Application'
          }
    }
    
    shadowJar {
                exclude 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:*'
               }
```

I use the following Pulumi code to deploy the code to the aws lamda function:

```
import * as aws from "@pulumi/aws"
import * as pulumi from "@pulumi/pulumi";
import  {petsExecutionRole} from "./PetsExecutionRole"

const stack = pulumi.getStack()
const handler= "com.baeldung.aws.handler.HttpV2LambdaHandler"


export const petsFunction = new aws.lambda.Function("pets-function", {
    code: new pulumi.asset.FileArchive("../app/build/libs/pets-all.jar"),   
    runtime: aws.lambda.Runtime.Java11,
    handler: handler,
    role: petsExecutionRole.arn,
    name: stack + '-' +"petsFunction",
    memorySize: 10240,
    timeout: 900,
    tracingConfig:{mode:"Active"},
    architectures:["arm64"],
    layers: [ "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:901920570463:layer:aws-otel-java-agent-arm64-ver-1-24-0:1",
              "arn:aws:lambda:eu-north-1:464622532012:layer:Datadog-Extension-ARM:43"], 
    environment: {
        variables: {
            AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER: "/opt/otel-handler",
            DD_LOGS_INJECTION:"true",
            DD_SITE: "datadoghq.eu",
            DD_ENV: "dev",
            DD_API_KEY: "xxxxxxx"
        }
            
        }

},
```

If run gradle bootRun and  run  curl http://localhost:8080 I get
curl  http://localhost:8080/users

[{"name":"John","surname":"Doe","emailAddress":"john.doe@baeldung.com"},{"name":"John","surname":"Doe","emailAddress":"john.doe-2@baeldung.com"}]%              steinko@Steins-MacBook-Pro inf %

The aws lamda function is called from a aws gateway
When I run a curl
curl https://h1t5hu3bu8.execute-api.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/dev/users
I get following error in the Cloadwatch log

Error loading class com.baeldung.aws.handler.HttpV2LambdaHandler: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext cannot be cast to class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext are in unnamed module of loader lambdainternal.CustomerClassLoader @4b960b5b)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:197)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.InitializationWrapper.start(InitializationWrapper.java:35)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.buildAndInitialize(SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.java:81)
at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getHttpApiV2ProxyHandler(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:110)
at com.baeldung.aws.handler.HttpV2LambdaHandler.(HttpV2LambdaHandler.java:16)
... 2 more

How do I fix this error ?

Comment: you should expect to run your lambda in development enviroments so you can test it locally